# How to shorten the KeyTime value of a StoryBoard DoubleAnimation

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

I want to change the KeyTimes of my DoubleAnimation. I have 5 KeyTimes and I have named them all Key1, Key2, Key3 etc.

The DoubleAnimation is called xAnimation. Does anyone know how I can change the KeyTimes?

Comment: Did you happen to check this blog out? http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Animations-in-depthndash-Overview-and-Getting-Started

Comment: Hi there. I read through that post and only saw:     fadeInAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)); This merely cuts my entire animation by more than half.

The problem is, I'm not sure how I can maintain the exact same animation but at a faster rate. The post doesn't show me that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set a higher speed ratio if you need the same animation, just faster or slower.

Set it as:

```
myStoryboard.SpeedRatio=2;
```

The above example will play your animation twice as fast. You can use a higher or lower number accordingly.